# Non-Invocable member 'Money.CurrencyEnum' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, square-connect

I am trying to implement square up to create charges, but at the line

```
Money money = new Money(amount, Money.CurrencyEnum(currency));
```

I keep getting the following error and can't figure out why:

```
Non-Invocable member 'Money.CurrencyEnum'  cannot be used like a method.
```

Thanks for any ideas

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Square.Connect.Api;
using Square.Connect.Client;
using Square.Connect.Model;

namespace Tester2
{
    public class Example
    {
        // Retrieving your location IDs
        public static void RetrieveLocations()
        {
            LocationApi _locationApi = new LocationApi();
            string authorization = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";
            var response = _locationApi.ListLocations(authorization);
        }

        // Charge the card nonce
        public static void ChargeNonce()
        {
            // Every payment you process for a given business have a unique idempotency key.
            // If you're unsure whether a particular payment succeeded, you can reattempt
            // it with the same idempotency key without worrying about double charging
            // the buyer.
            string idempotencyKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            // Monetary amounts are specified in the smallest unit of the applicable currency.
            // This amount is in cents. It's also hard-coded for $1, which is not very useful.
            int amount = 100;
            string currency = "USD";
            Money money = new Money(amount, Money.CurrencyEnum(currency));

            string nonce = "YOUR_NONCE";
            string authorization = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";
            string locationId = "YOUR_LOCATION_ID";
            ChargeRequest body = new ChargeRequest(AmountMoney: money, IdempotencyKey: idempotencyKey, CardNonce: nonce);
            TransactionApi transactionApi = new TransactionApi();
            var response = transactionApi.Charge(authorization, locationId, body);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `Enum.Parse` presumably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Money.CurrencyEnum` is an enumerated type. It is not a method. Therefore, you can't call it like a method.

In the case you've got, you seem to know which value you want, so just use it:

```
Money money = new Money(amount, Money.CurrencyEnum.USD);
```

If you must parse a string, try this:

```
var strCurr = "USD";
Money.CurrencyEnum currency;

if (!Enum.TryParse(strCurr, out currency))
{
    throw new Exception("Bad currency type: " + strCurr);
}

Money money = new Money(amount, currency);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an enum as if it were a method. If you would like to convert a string to an enum value you can use [`Enum.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if(Enum.TryParse("USD", out Money.CurrencyEnum value))
{
    Money money = new Money(amount, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because Money.CurrencyEnum is probably property and NOT a method, so you can't just call it like this:

```
Money.CurrencyEnum(currency)
```

Question is based on what it actually is. If it is property, just use this:

```
Money.CurrencyEnum
```

If it is sub-class enumeration then you can parse your currency value and transform it into your enum type:

```
var e = (Money.CurrencyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(Money.CurrencyEnum), currency);
```